# Extracting/Parsing from a PDF to CSV using R?

Tags: r, parsing, pdf, data-extraction

I am trying to extract data from a poorly formatted PDF into a .csv file for geocoding. The data I am concerned with are the locations of Farmers' Markets in Colorado for 2018 (https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/sites/default/files/Colorado%20Farmers%27%20Markets.pdf). The necessary fields I am looking to have are Business_Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Hours, Season, Email, and Website. The trouble is that the data are all in one column, and not all of the entries have 100% complete data. That is to say that one entry may have five attributes under it (name, address, hours, zip, website) and another may only have 2 lines of the attributes (name, address).

I found an embedded map of locations here (http://www.coloradofarmers.org/find-markets/) that references the PDF file above. I was able to save this map to MyMaps and copy/paste the table to a CSV, but there are missing entries.

Is there a way to cleanly parse this data from PDF to CSV? I imagine what I need to do is create a dictionary of Colorado towns with markets (e.g. 'Denver', 'Canon City', 'Telluride') and then basically have R look through the column, put every new line that exists between look-up cities on the previous city's line all in one row in separate field columns. Or as one comma-delimited field to then parse out based on what the fields looks like.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#Set the working directory
setwd("C:/Users/bwhite/Desktop")

#download the PDF of data
?download.file
download.file("https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/sites/default/files/Colorado%20Farmers%27%20Markets.pdf", destfile = "./ColoradoMarkets2018.pdf", method = "auto", quiet = FALSE, mode = "w", cacheOK=TRUE)

#import the pdf table library from CRAN
install.packages("pdftables")

library(pdftables)

#convert pdf to CSV
?convert_pdf
convert_pdf("Colorado Farmers' Markets.pdf",output_file = "FarmersMarkets.csv", 
            format = "csv", message = TRUE, api_key = "n7qgsnz2nkun")

# read in CSV
Markets18 <-read.csv("./FarmersMarkets.csv")

#create a look-up table list of Colorado cities
install.packages("htmltab")
library(htmltab)

CityList <-htmltab("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_Colorado",1)
names(CityList)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can only attempt to extract information that is consistent. I'm not an expert but I tried to build a logic for some part. Pages 2-20 are somewhat free of dirty data. Also if you notice, each group can be split at p.m. (for most part). Since number of columns is different for some of them, it was difficult to build one logic. Even the extracted dataframe would require some transformation.

```
library(pdftools)

text<-pdf_text("Colorado Farmers' Markets.pdf")
library(plyr)

new<-data.frame()


text4<-data.frame(Reduce(rbind, text),row.names =c() ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for (i in 2:20){

list1<-text4[i,1]
list1<-strsplit(list1,'p.m.')
final<-data.frame(Reduce(rbind, list1),row.names =c() ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for (i in 1:dim(final)[1]){
  c<-final[i,]
  c<-strsplit(c,'\n')

  new<-rbind.fill(new,data.frame(t(data.frame(c,row.names =c()))))
}
}
```